# Hide Toaster Notification Before Navigation

Tags: angular6

I have two component say component1,component2 in my angular 6 application. I have implemented toaster notification on component1 to show some message. But when I navigate to Html of component2 this notification remains open and I do not want this.

On HTML of component1

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/', rowData.employeeId]" (click)="HidePopup()"></a>
     <emp-popup *ngIf="shouldDisplay" [toasterMessage]="message">
        </emp-popup>
```

On TypeScript   of component1

```
HidePopup(){
    this.shouldDisplay=false;
    }
```

I tried to do by HidePopup() function but still issue remains same. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

hello try to use router navigation in function
in

remove [routerLink] from a tag and add it in function

```
constractor(private router: Router){} 
HidePopup(){
  this.shouldDisplay=false;
  this.router.navigate['/someURL']
}
```

Comment: Same result here, it keeps open. It works only when I do not navigate to other page then it goes away

Comment: in your second component, do you have *ngIf="shouldDisplay" and shouldDisplay varable?

Comment: No, I can access emp-popup only from first component

Comment: hmmm, meybe you problem in true and false,  are you try  add  --> '' ! ''  
*ngIf="!shouldDisplay"

Comment: Well I tried this already before. It seems that some functionality from HTML action is different from behavior from component action in Angular. I also tried to fade in/out on page load,it did not worked but same code actually works on some Html action like button click.